# Why isn't the Java compiler (specifically its parser) able to understand this statement

Tags: java

I have the following two classes (in two separate files).

```
public class Foo
{
    public static class A
    {
        public static final boolean FLAG = false;
    }

    public final A A = new A();
}


public class Bar
{
    void method()
    {
         if (Foo.A.FLAG)  <<<< this is giving "Cannot make static ref to non-static field
            // do something
           ;
    }
}
```

My question is, why isn't the compiler able to recorgnise that by `Foo.A`, I meant the class `A`, not the member, which also happens to be named `A`?

Comment: Why would you want to name a variable and a class the same thing?

Comment: If Java allows it, then I coudln't see why-not....

Comment: @Barzee even though this example seems contrived, it's not far fetched that in real code a name can be interpreted in multiple ways, so there should be a way to pick one.

Comment: I wish my ethics didn't forbid my upvoting that comment.

Comment: for a more contrived example where the same name can be used for multiple meanings, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690135

Comment: One of many reasons to follow the java naming convention

Comment: This problem is known as the "Color Color" problem in the analysis of C#, which takes an interesting approach to solving it. See section 7.6.4.1 "Identical simple names and type names" of the C# 5 specification for details.

Comment: @EricLippert It probably won't work in Java since a nested type, a static method, an instance method, and a field(static/instance) can all share the same name. What saves Java form ambiguity is its capitalization convention:)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is called [obscuring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.2), an obscure feature/limitation of Java

> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be
>   interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these
>   situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that **a variable will be chosen
>   in preference to a type**, and that a type will be chosen in preference
>   to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a
>   visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that
>   such a declaration is obscured.

If the variable `A` was `static`, it would compile since you can can access `static` members on object references.

---

Also `FLAG` hasn't been initialized.

Comment: yes, thanks for the notes on `FLAG` (wasn't the focus of the question, though. :) )

Comment: @OneTwoThree I had to bring it up so that the change I suggested you try would work :p

Comment: Well, `A` had to be instance-member (the reason of which is hard to see here, cos I sort of over-simplify `Foo`), but even if I made it a static member, I would also not like to see the warning of accessing static-member with object-ref.

Comment: +1 for you. And thank you for the links to the ref. (But zhong.j.yu's answer really solved teh problem. :) )

Comment: @OneTwoThree It's up to you obviously, but zhong's answer doesn't answer your question: `My question is, why isn't the compiler able to recorgnise that by Foo.A, I meant the class A, not the member, which also happens to be named A?`.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right. I should probably be nice and choose the correct answer. :) (I voted his answer because I didnt know we could do what he did in the memthod-decl!)

Answer (score 4):

Some ways to access the flag:

```
<Foo_A extends Foo.A> void test1()
{
    if(Foo_A.FLAG)
        ;
}

void test2()
{
    class Foo_A extends Foo.A{}
    if(Foo_A.FLAG)
        ;
}

-------------------------------------
import pkg.Foo.A;

public class Bar
{
    void test3()
    {
        if(A.FLAG)
            ;
    }
}
```

in these contexts, `"Foo.A"` can only be interpreted as a type, not a variable.

Comment: Hmm, (haven't pasted this into an IDE an compile it, but) I've never seen the syntax on the first line before...

Comment: Oooh, I understand it now! +++++1 for the awesomeness. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because inner classes require an instance of the enclosing type. If you dont have an instance of Foo, A doesnt exist.

Edit - This is incorrect, but the reason why is informative. see the comments below:

Comment: This is not true for `static` inner classes, and... oh, look, there's one!

Comment: Foo.A can also refer to the inner **static** class.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato I will have to investigate this further, thanks!

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato There is no such thing as a `static` inner class because `static` is the opposite of *inner*. @markw There are inner classes which *do not require an enclosing instance*. This is mainly about terminology, but using wrong terminology makes you produce false statements.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik do you have any links to documentation on these exceptions?

Comment: Of course, it's in the JLS. Go to the section on inner classes, for example.

Comment: @barzee A *nested* class is either *inner* or *static nested*. Therefore they are opposites.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : indeed, `static` **nested** classes. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Barzee [`An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

Comment: Quote from JLS: "An instance of an inner class `I` whose declaration occurs in a static context has no lexically enclosing instances."

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html

See the section on inner classes.